# How to access object from pointer?

Tags: javascript, ios, pointers, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an application where the user get notified whenever there is a new comment on their post. I'm using parse as a backend.

I have following data structure

Comment table

> objectId
>
> Comment
>
> commentedPost

Post table

> objectId
>
> createdBy

and I already set a pointer(to PFUser) on installation table called User.

I try to querying the commentedPost>Post>createdBy with User on installation.

I've tried the code below:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Comments', function(request) {
commentQuery.include("commentedPost");
var post = request.object.get("commentedPost");
var poster = post.get("createdBy");

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('jooveUser', poster);

Parse.Push.send({
    where: query, // Set our Installation query.
    data: {
        alert: message = 'hahahahahaha'
    }
}, {
    success: function() {
        response.success();
    },
    error: function(err) {
        response.error();
    }
});
});
```

But, it does nothing or sending any notifications. What did I do wrong? How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Ok, first of all I'm not sure where does `commentQuery.include("commentedPost");` come from, do you really need it there? Secondly add `console.log(variable_content);` after `var post = ...` and also after `var poster = ...` to see what data are you working with (after deploying to cloud and saving comment you can check in Parse Log). Then we'll take it from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to grab pointer (`user`) inside the pointer (`post`) you need to first fetch the `post` pointer. Small modification to your code (specially pay attention to the `fetch().then()` part of the code):

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Comments', function(request) {

    // read pointer async
    request.object.get("commentedPost").fetch().then(function(post){

        // 'post' is the commentedPost object here
        var poster = post.get('createdBy');

        // proceed with the rest of your code - unchanged
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.equalTo('jooveUser', poster);

        Parse.Push.send({
            where: query, // Set our Installation query.
            data: {
                alert: message = 'hahahahahaha'
            }
        }, {
            success: function() {
                response.success();
            },
            error: function(err) {
                response.error();
            }
        }); 
    });

});
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: you just made my day, I've been searching for hours for this solution :D Thanks.

Comment: but How can I prevent receving notifications when I commented on my own post?

Comment: haven't tried that but I think `Parse.User.current()` gives you access to the user who's logged in and sending the query ... so simply compare `Parse.User.current()` against poster, that should do the trick